# 404 redirect if a URL string value isn't in the database or valid?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a 'video' page that is passed a variable by the URL (`video.php?id=VALUE`). This `id` value is used throughout the page to pull in various details about the video - title, a still, year etc.

I want to display a 404/error if an incorrect value (/something not in the database) is entered into the string, and display the page with corresponding values pulled from the database if the value is correct

My code is currently structured like this:

```
<?php 
    $video = $_GET['video'];
    $videodata = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM video WHERE siteurl = ? LIMIT 1");
    $videodata->execute([$video]);
    ?>

    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

     <title>   
     <?php
     foreach ($videodata as $videodatas) {
     echo "{$videodatas['title']}</title>";

     echo "<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"{$videodatas['title']}\"/>"; }?>
     <meta name="description" content="Description lives here">

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

     <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" />


     <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/style.css">


    </head>
```

When this successfully matches it generates the page, listing the correct video title in the `<title>` tags and throughout the rest of the page.

However, when I'm testing an incorrect variable in the URL/something that's not in my database the page is spitting out a completely blank page that includes all of the raw HTML in the `<title>` tag.

Any help (even in the direction of a tutorial on how to achieve this) would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I've tried writing some code as a test with the intention to replace the `if` and `else` statements when I have it working. The code doesn't work at the moment and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong...:

```
<?php 
$video = $_GET['video']; 
$videodata = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM video WHERE site url =:siteurl LIMIT 1"); // check db for :siteurl value

$videodata->bindParam(':siteurl', $_GET['video'], PDO::PARAM_STR); // bind site url to $_Get Value...

$videodata->execute([$video]); // execute

if($videodata->rowCount()) { // If videodata [url string] returns data then... 
 echo '<b>hello world... this entry is there!</b>';
 } else {
 echo 'NO .... ITS NOT THERE';
 }
;
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to get this going? You'll want to check the value returned from the database and take action based on that value. These are the docs for [if statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) and [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) which might help you.

Comment: Please do not redirect to your 404 page. If an item is not found or not valid, display the 404 message in that URL.

Comment: @Tordek - is there a reason that displaying a 404 in the same URL is better from a usability or accessibility standpoint?

@Henders - I'm quite new to PDO (and PHP for that matter) and have been kind of pulling together code from different tutorials and other advice on here, so I'm not too sure exactly how well my code stands up or if it should all be nested inside an `if` statement...

Comment: Yes, it's for usability. A redirect means "You can find the resource in a different location"; you're telling the user "The data for <inexistent item> is there, and also there's nothing there"; just reply with a 404 code and "the item was not found" or whatever.

For one use case, imagine if I manually type the URL, and make a typo. Suddenly I'm at a 404 page (as I should) but my URL bar says "404.php" instead of the URL I typed; I can't just correct it, but must now type it again.

Comment: @Tordek - Ah, ok amazing - got you. Makes perfect sense.